# How to mount React component after dynamic him import

Tags: reactjs, import

tryed to this code in React component:

```
this.setState({
    module: import ('../1superSet/dashboard/containers/Dashboard'), // eslint-disable-line
  });
```

- import must be after some request.
Next:

```
{this.state.module && this.state.module.then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res)
      const Dashboard = res
      return (<Dashboard />)
    })}
```

But React cant render this because Dashboard is object:

"React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render a `Promise` (`this.state.module.then`). You should load the Component and only set it in the side after it's loaded.

```js
foo() {
  const Dashboard = await import('../1superSet/dashboard/containers/Dashboard');
  this.setState({ Dashboard });
}
```

Then you can render it by doing something like this:

```js
render() {
  const { Dashboard } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      { Dashboard && (<Dashboard/>)
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Take a look at [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) for even more simplifications and added features.

Comment: Also this code returned: "React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: Dashboard returned Connect function for my component